# How do I write an MP4 file pulled from a website?

Tags: python

I have been practicing web-scraping with python and have been attempting to download a video from a website.

```
url = 'http://www.toonova.net/we-bare-bears-episode-0'

res = requests.get(url, stream = True)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

video = str(soup.select('iframe')[1])
video = video.split('"')
src = video[3]

res = requests.get(src)
res.raise_for_status()

video_file = open(os.path.join('We Bare Bears', os.path.basename(src)), 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(1024):
    video_file.write(chunk)
video_file.close()
```

This code creates an MP4 file with the appropriate extension, but the file appears to be corrupted. I'm still pretty inexperienced with this and would appreciate any tips on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you just did is create a file with extension of MP4 without actually encode it. You can use this library to encode desired video format [Python Media library](http://pymedia.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! It looks like I would want to use the functions defined in vplayer.py, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use them. Would you be able to point me to a good tutorial?